# Modular forms inducing functions on $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: modular-forms

I am familiar with the classical thoery of modular forms.

I've heard that a modular form on gives rise to a function on $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ (or maybe $GL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, or even $GL_2(\mathbb{A})$ - matrices over the adeles).

I'm confused, and googling about it seems to suggest a relation to *Strong Approximation* (which I'm not familiar with). Maybe it's stronger than what I need, because I'm curious mainly about getting a function on $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and not the adeles, but I can always restrict such map on adelic matrices.

> Given a modular (or even cusp) form $f$, what is the corresponding function on $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. What does it remember about $f$ and what does it forget? Is it left/right invariant under some subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$?

Comment: There is a very nice account of this in Bump's book "Automorphic Forms and Representations", which you might like to look at.